# Xamarin, Plugin.FilePicker -> Exception: "...View=DecorView

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

In my Xamarin project I use Plugin.FilePicker, everything works except one exception.

If I perform the action of selecting a file from 2 to 6 times, and the same number of times I click the button back I get an exception:

```
Unhandled Exception:

Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: View=DecorView@b10016d[] not attached to window manager
```

The class in which the plugin is used is made up entirely of try, catch blocks. In another class where I use the methods of the previous class I also equipped with try, catch blocks - for checking only. It does not catch an exception anywhere.

The project is written on Android and UWP. It occurs on the android, but on the UWP no.

Any ideas?

***EDIT***

Thanks for answer :) This is part of my code:

```
public  class FilePickerService
    {
        private FileData fileData;
        public FilePickerService()
        {
            fileData = new FileData();
        }

        public async Task<bool> pickFile()
        {
            try
            {
                fileData = await CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile();
                if (fileData == null)
                    return false; // user canceled file picking
                else
                {
                    string fileName = fileData.FileName;
                    string contents = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(fileData.DataArray);

                    System.Console.WriteLine("File name chosen: " + fileName);
                    System.Console.WriteLine("File data: " + contents);

                    return true;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("Exception choosing file: " + ex.ToString());
                return false;
            }
        }
        public FileData getFileData()
        {
            try
            {
                if (fileData != null)
                {
                    return fileData;
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                var error = ex.Message;
                return null;
            }

        }
        public string getFileName()
        {
            try
            {
                string fileName = fileData.FileName;
                return fileName;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                var error = ex.Message;
                return "";
            }


        }

        public string getFileContents()
        {
            try
            {
                string contents = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(fileData.DataArray);
                return contents;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var error = ex.Message;
                return "";
            }

        }

        public bool fileIsPicture()
        {
            try
            {
                string fileName = fileData.FileName;
                bool isJPG = false;
                bool isPNG = false;

                isJPG = Path.GetExtension(fileName).Equals(".jpg", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) || Path.GetExtension(fileName).Equals(".jpeg", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
                isPNG = Path.GetExtension(fileName).Equals(".png", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

                if (isJPG == true || isPNG == true)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                var error = ex.Message;
                return false;
            }
        }

        public bool fileIsExist()
        {
            try
            {
                if (fileData != null)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                var error = ex.Message;
                return false;
            }

        }
    }
```

..
A similar code can be selected for 3 pictures. Below I presented support for 1 out of 3.

```
    public Image imagePhotoOne;
    public Image imageTakePhotoOne;
    private Service.FilePickerService serviceImagePickerOne;

//Another code...

    imagePhotoOne = new Image();
    imageTakePhotoOne = new Image();
    serviceImagePickerOne = new Service.FilePickerService();

//Another code...

     TapGestureRecognizer tapGestureImageTakePhotoOne = new TapGestureRecognizer();
                tapGestureImageTakePhotoOne.Tapped += async (sender, e) =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var status = await serviceImagePickerOne.pickFile();

                        if (status == true)
                        {
                            if (serviceImagePickerOne.fileIsPicture() == true)
                            {
                                imagePhotoOne.IsVisible = true;
                                imageTakePhotoOne.IsVisible = false;
                                imagePhotoOne.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
                                {
                                    return new MemoryStream(serviceImagePickerOne.getFileData().DataArray);
                                });

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                await Task.Delay(100);
                                UserDialogs.Instance.Toast("Zdjecie nie jest w formacje .jpg/.jpeg/.png");
                                await Task.Delay(100);
                                imagePhotoOne.IsVisible = false;
                                imageTakePhotoOne.IsVisible = true;
                                imagePhotoOne.Source = null;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            await Task.Delay(100);
                            UserDialogs.Instance.Toast("Nie wybrano pliku");
                            await Task.Delay(100);
                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        var error = ex.Message;
                    }

                };
                imageTakePhotoOne.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureImageTakePhotoOne);
```

A similar code can be used to select 3 files. Below I presented support for 1 out of 3.

```
public Label labelFileOne;
public Image imageTakeFileOne;
private Service.FilePickerService serviceFilePickerOne;

//Code create elements

 TapGestureRecognizer tapGestureImageTakeFileOne = new TapGestureRecognizer();
            tapGestureImageTakeFileOne.Tapped += async (sender, e) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    var status = await serviceFilePickerOne.pickFile();

                    if (status == true)
                    {
                        if (serviceFilePickerOne.getFileData() != null)
                        {
                            labelFileOne.IsVisible = true;
                            labelFileOne.Text = serviceFilePickerOne.getFileName();
                            imageTakeFileOne.IsVisible = false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            await Task.Delay(100);
                            UserDialogs.Instance.Toast("Nie udało się wczytać pliku");
                            await Task.Delay(100);
                            labelFileOne.IsVisible = false;
                            labelFileOne.Text = "";
                            imageTakeFileOne.IsVisible = false;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await Task.Delay(100);
                        UserDialogs.Instance.Toast("Nie wybrano pliku");
                        await Task.Delay(100);
                    }
                }
               catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    var error = ex.Message;
                }


            };
            imageTakeFileOne.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureImageTakeFileOne);
```

**The error occurs when I use Plugin.FilePicker 3 to 6 times, but I do not choose any file every time.**

Answer (score 0):

**Answer Edited**
Looks like you need media picker as you're choosing only png and jpeg files. I reproduced the issue with the plugin you're using. Please use xam.plugin.media instead, it should fix your issue.